# Laravel Project Port can't access on Docker with Port

Tags: laravel, docker, xampp

I have this configuration on my `etc/httpd.conf`

```
 <VirtualHost *:0207>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/api_tk/public"
  ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>
 listen 0207
```

This is working on my local

So I'm trying to implement this on my `docker`

My Xampp dashboard can be accessible using this link ip

`192.168.0.XX:3030`

When this `IP` entered to the browser it redirects to `xampp`    `/dashboard` where the dashboard of xampp can be seen.

Is it possible to access my laravel project through `PORT` in this kind of setup? On my local I can access my laravel project using `192.168.0.XX:207/myapi/login`

But when I try using docker, I can't imagine how can I done this one

This is my Docker of 3021 with different ports. Image just to clarify

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far? how you build the image? is there an error?

Comment: since my xampp dashboard is accessible using this ip `192.168.0.XX:3030/dashboard` is it possible to do something like this? `192.168.0.XX:3030:207/myapi/login` since my laravel project is set as port 207

Currently that's what I have done right now.

Comment: there should be only port in the url `192.168.0.XX:0207/myapi/login` or `192.168.0.XX:3030/myapi/login`. you can map any port of the host with container port.

Comment: Could you switch from port 207 to something above 1024 ? Just to avoid the "private" range for ports. Could you also share docker configuration?